# Interpolate between ruby and javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails 4 app where I have a script like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(function (){
      $(document).on("change",".selectProduct", function (){
         var selectValue = $(this).val();
         alert("<%= render 'product_form/test', f:builder %>");
      });
   });
</script>
```

Basically, what I want to do is have the selectValue (which is the value of a select), be rendered in the ruby code. So something like:

```
var selectValue = $(this).val();
alert("<%= render 'product_form/#{selectValue}', f:builder %>");
```

Comment: You can't make Ruby works directly with Ruby: **Ruby** is executed on the **server-side**, whereas **Javascript** is executed on the **client-side**. You need to send the value selected with Javascript, the server responds (in your case, with HTML), the client gets the response and handle (in your case, display) the response.

Comment: You can generate `.js` template in Rails view and interpolate it in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked for (you can't call Ruby from JS except for sending AJAX request), but this hybrid approach is close:

- Generate normal Rails view with e.g. Mustache.js (https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) substitutions:

`... <div>Product: {{product}}</div> ...`

- Render it to a string and pass to JS.
- `alert(Mustache.render(your_template, {product: selectValue}))`